# javascript for...in using an object

Tags: javascript

JavaScript [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) states:

> A different property name is assigned to `variable` on each iteration.

So with that in mind I tried this:

```
var cup = new Object();
        cup.color = 'red';
        cup.design = 'regular';
        cup.weight = '2.8lbs.';
        cup.material = 'ceramic';

        for( property in cup )
        {
            console.log( cup.property );
        }
```

This returns `undefined`. I know that this would work with `cup[property]`. If  the property name is assigned to the cup in the above loop why wouldn't my aforementioned example work? Why does it only work using brackets?

References to documentation would help.

Comment: You are looking for a value named 'property', which is undefined.

Comment: come i give up you that much time at least give my post a `vote up`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the ECMA Script 5.1 Specification, [property accessors](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) are defined as

> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> or the bracket notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ Expression ] 
> CallExpression [ Expression ]
> ```

So, when you use `.`, the following string will be treated as the actual property name. In this case, you don't have a property named `property`. That is why you are getting `undefined`.

When you use a bracket, the expression within the brackets will be evaluated to get the actual property name and then the property will be accessed. That is why it works when you use bracket notation.

Comment: Thanks! That reference really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Because `cup.property` and `cup[property]` have fundamentally different meanings. Consult your nearest JS tutorial for details. `cup.property` refers to the property with the name `"property"`. `cup[property]` refers to the property with the name given by the value of the variable `property`. You are looking for the latter.

Comment: you are contradicting @Oleg

Answer (score 1):

`cup.property` is exactly the same as `cup['property']` and the property named "property" has never been defined on your object. You never actually assign it. You're only trying to read it in your `for..in` loop.

This, however, will log all values on your object:

```
for(property in cup) {
    console.log(cup[property]);
}

// red
// regular
// 2.8lbs.
// ceramic
```

Comment: you are contradicting @torazaburo

Comment: you say cup.property is exactly the same as cup['property']  but he says that cup.property and cup[property] have fundamentally different meanings.

Comment: @anni `cup['property']` is not the same as `cup[property]`, you're confusing strings and variables.

Answer (score 1):

`property` is returned as a string. In JS, objects are collections of key value pairs (dictionaries if you want). JS objects store the property names as strings. Therefore you can look up a property by providing its string value.

```
var foo = {}; // this has 0 "own" keys
foo.x = "Hello";
foo["y"] = "World";
// now foo looks like this {"x": "Hello", "y": "World"}

var prop = "y";
console.log( foo.y ); // World
console.log( foo["y"] ); // World
console.log( foo[prop] ); // World
console.log( foo.prop ); // undefined, because it looks for a property named "prop"
```

Bracket notation is useful when you have keys which are not legal to use with dot notation.

```
var bar = {};
bar["me@mail.com"] = true;
bar["hello world"] = 12;
console.log( bar["me@mail.com"] ); // true
console.log( bar["hello world"] ); // 12
```

Note that since arrays are objects the above applies to them as well.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log( arr["1"] ); // b
console.log( arr["length"] ); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

i tell you if you are suppose defined the cup variable then

```
cup.color   // red
cup.weight  // 2.8lbs
cup.height  // undefined because it is not been defined
```

what should be concluded from this..

that it returns undefined when that property is not defined.

Now in this case you see it is retuning `undefined` 4 times as i checked this code in google console 
because there are 4 properties.. what that menas is that name of the property is not been assigned properly to the variable `property` and when you tried to retrieve the unknown property it returned undefined.  but this is wrong.

actuall the method of retrieving is wrong. ofcourse this not chance of assigning wrong name of property by the code engine. insted of retrieving like this `cupt.property` you should write `cup[property]`